# Why is the "% for loops" comparably memory-expensive to the summation algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've been doing C++ programming and did some programming quizzes in Hacker Rank, specifically the Project Euler ++ integrated problem on Using Multiples of 3 and 5 (First Problem) . I tried to do a "brute-force" algorithm, using the modulo (%) operator. But, I receive a time-out, upon reading up on the forums, the % in a for loop is way more expensive than applying the summation algorithm.

---

Edit [December 23, 2015] 
 ------------
I realised that my previous question   ***"Though both being brute-force, how is the modulo then way more memory-expensive to the expense of a time-out?"***   should be considered a void question because I didn't realise that the summation algorithm was a brute-force algorithm. According to a summary of the comments section, various users have commented that the % is definitely not what is causing the timeout as the modulo operator is very lightweight. According to user  ***Ishamael*** too, I see that my solution:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    int sum, num;

   for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
     sum = 0;
     num = 0;
     cin >> num;
     for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
        if ((j % 3 == 0) || (j % 5 == 0)) {
        sum += j;
        }
     }

     cout << sum << endl;

   }

  return 0;

 }
```

gives me a timeout not because of the modulo operator but because of the nested for loops. The bottomline of the problem is the usage of for loops as a solution to the algorithm.

I sought help from a top-coder in Quora ( **Razziman T.V.** ) advised me on how to use the Summation Algorithm as referred to in the forum section:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
   int T;
   cin >> T;
   long long sum, num;

        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
         sum = 0;
         num = 0;
         cin >> num;

         if(num > 0) num = num - 1;

         long long n3 = floor(num / 3);
         long long n5 = floor(num / 5);
         long long n15 = floor(num / 15);

         sum = (n3 * (n3 + 1) / 2 * 3) + ((n5 * (n5 + 1) / 2) * 5)  -  ((n15 * (n15 + 1) / 2) * 15);    

               cout << sum << endl;

              return 0;
        }
  }
```

In this solution, it is shown that we can get the summation of multiples of 3... (*derived from (3 + 6 + 9...[floor(n / 3) * 3] / 3 = 1 + 2 + 3...floor(n / 3) )*. Apply it to 5 also and 15. Add the summation of 3 and 5 and subtract it from those of 15 as to remove repetition. Do not forget to use long long also because some test cases might hold large number size.

**Happy Coding!**  :)

Comment: `%` is a constant time operation.  Loops are not.  So `%` is faster than most loops.  You'll need to provide a citation.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will be so much easier to understand what you are describing.

Comment: `%` is extremely memory-light; in fact, it usually doesn't even touch RAM. Also, `%` and nested loops are way too dissimilar to compare. We need a lot more context to understand what you're talking about. Why do you think you're even running into memory problems?

Comment: It's because I got a timeout in using such, the modulo, but I went to the discussions and their proposed nested for loops, it passes the test cases

Comment: Are you using integers? Floating point modulo is equivalent to divide and hence super slow.

Comment: Oh...But I'm using integers only

Comment: Neither of your examples use a measurable amount of memory.  The speed of the `%` code is faster than the one with the `for` loop, although they both finish under a millisecond.

Comment: would this mean that this is just a hacker rank bug?

Comment: I don't think so.  You haven't given enough information to say.  Maybe provide a link to what you're talking about and provide complete code?

Comment: @AlexBrown: Isn't integer modulo also like divide and hence super slow?

Comment: @Mehrdad There's no such thing as floating-point modulo. Floating-point divide instructions typically just give you the exact quotient as a floating-point number. And, yes, integer modulo literally is a divide instruction on Intel CPUs, so it's quite slow compared to any other integer operation, but we're still talking about nanoseconds.

Comment: You talk about nested for loops, yet don't show any as code?

Comment: @reirab: There's a floating-point modulo operation; it's just that it's [`fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) rather than `%`. There are even [CPU](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_107.html) [instructions](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_108.html) for it.

Comment: @reirab: "There's no such thing as floating-point modulo"? What about `fmod`?

Comment: I don't know what happened, but now it passed already...

Comment: 2 cases didn't pass as they were timeout

Comment: Online contests often make solving problems with brute force expensive by using large test cases. The idea is that you should come up with a more efficient way of solving the problem. You can still keep your brute-force approach to verify that the more efficient code works. For example, if you want the sum of all numbers from 1 to N, you could sum them in a loop, but you could just as well calculate N·(N + 1)/2.

Comment: "Programmers" may jest you for complaining about `memory` when experiencing `time-out`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are talking about this problem:

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler001

If yes, than note that `N` is up to `10^9`. A solution on hacker rank is expected to be fast, which means it should finish in couple seconds. Your brute force solution most likely will not finish in 2 seconds -- try passing it `1000000000` as input and measure how much time it takes.

This problem requires one to think, and come up with a very efficient solution (which will have no loops), not to implement a brute force approach.

Comment: I suppose the poster's solution _will_ finish in a couple of seconds easily, but a solution within a microsecond or so was expected.

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop is redundant.
I also removed console reading, because use of it was unclear. You can modify this to get more universal solution.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int T;
    T = 1000; // Can be replaced with cin >> T
    int sum;
    sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < T; j++) {
        if ((j % 3 == 0) || (j % 5 == 0)) {
            sum += j;
        }
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The outer loop is over different test cases. After reading `T`, you should read `T` numbers for which you calculate the sum. (In a way the outer loop is redundanf, however, because you do the same calculation over and over again. When you calculate the sum for 1000, you have calculated the sum for all smaller numbers on the way.)

Comment: But T was supposedly "Test Cases"

Comment: Many inputs can be given

Comment: Ok, now I see. What I put here is a solution to base [problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1) at Project Euler